# Angular: inserting firebase collection inside a constant

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ng-bootstrap

I have a Datatable with [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/table/complete/stackblitz.html) that use a static array to show data. I have 3 files:

country.ts, which declares the values I'll read

```
export interface Country {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  flag: string;
  area: number;
  population: number;
}
```

and contries.ts which is an array from where I'm going to read the data:

```
import {Country} from './country';
export const COUNTRIES: Country[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Russia',
    flag: 'f/f3/Flag_of_Russia.svg',
    area: 17075200,
    population: 146989754
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'France',
    flag: 'c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg',
    area: 640679,
    population: 64979548
  },
]
```

I need to populate countries.ts with firebase data, something like that:

```
import {Country} from './country';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
export const COUNTRIES: Country[] = firestore.collection('users').valueChanges();
```

That way I could get the **country.service.ts** working and read the dynamic data to sort and paginate the datatable like the [example of ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/table/complete/stackblitz.html).

**country.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

import {BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, Subject} from 'rxjs';

import {Country} from './country';
import {COUNTRIES} from './countries';
import {DecimalPipe} from '@angular/common';
import {debounceTime, delay, switchMap, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {SortColumn, SortDirection} from './sortable.directive';

interface SearchResult {
  countries: Country[];
  total: number;
}

interface State {
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
  searchTerm: string;
  sortColumn: SortColumn;
  sortDirection: SortDirection;
}

const compare = (v1: string | number, v2: string | number) => v1 < v2 ? -1 : v1 > v2 ? 1 : 0;

function sort(countries: Country[], column: SortColumn, direction: string): Country[] {
  if (direction === '' || column === '') {
    return countries;
  } else {
    return [...countries].sort((a, b) => {
      const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
      return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
    });
  }
}

function matches(country: Country, term: string, pipe: PipeTransform) {
  return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
    || pipe.transform(country.area).includes(term)
    || pipe.transform(country.population).includes(term);
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CountryService {
  private _loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  private _search$ = new Subject<void>();
  private _countries$ = new BehaviorSubject<Country[]>([]);
  private _total$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  private _state: State = {
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 4,
    searchTerm: '',
    sortColumn: '',
    sortDirection: ''
  };

  constructor(private pipe: DecimalPipe) {
    this._search$.pipe(
      tap(() => this._loading$.next(true)),
      debounceTime(200),
      switchMap(() => this._search()),
      delay(200),
      tap(() => this._loading$.next(false))
    ).subscribe(result => {
      this._countries$.next(result.countries);
      this._total$.next(result.total);
    });

    this._search$.next();
  }

  get countries$() { return this._countries$.asObservable(); }
  get total$() { return this._total$.asObservable(); }
  get loading$() { return this._loading$.asObservable(); }
  get page() { return this._state.page; }
  get pageSize() { return this._state.pageSize; }
  get searchTerm() { return this._state.searchTerm; }

  set page(page: number) { this._set({page}); }
  set pageSize(pageSize: number) { this._set({pageSize}); }
  set searchTerm(searchTerm: string) { this._set({searchTerm}); }
  set sortColumn(sortColumn: SortColumn) { this._set({sortColumn}); }
  set sortDirection(sortDirection: SortDirection) { this._set({sortDirection}); }

  private _set(patch: Partial<State>) {
    Object.assign(this._state, patch);
    this._search$.next();
  }

  private _search(): Observable<SearchResult> {
    const {sortColumn, sortDirection, pageSize, page, searchTerm} = this._state;

    // 1. sort
    let countries = sort(COUNTRIES, sortColumn, sortDirection);

    // 2. filter
    countries = countries.filter(country => matches(country, searchTerm, this.pipe));
    const total = countries.length;

    // 3. paginate
    countries = countries.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, (page - 1) * pageSize + pageSize);
    return of({countries, total});
  }
}
```

Has someone already had to do this?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please mark questions with the correct tag going forward.

Answer (score 0):

`.valueChanges()` returns an `Observable<Country[]>`, so you have to `pipe` your filtering and sorting logic within the `_search()` method.

And remember to unsubscribe as soon as you can (eg. when the table is destroyed).

```js
private _search(): Observable<SearchResult> {
    const {sortColumn, sortDirection, pageSize, page, searchTerm} = this._state;

    return COUNTRIES.pipe(
      map(countryList => sort(countryList, sortColumn, sortDirection)),
      map(countryList => countryList.filter(country => matches(country, searchTerm, this.pipe))),
      map(countryList => ({
        total: countryList.length,
        countries: countries.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, (page - 1) * pageSize + pageSize)
      }))
    );

  }
```

Comment: Could you show a code example of how I could do this?

Comment: Sure. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But how I get the object from firebase? I tried to decalre: public USERSLIST: Observable<Users[]>; and in the constructor call: this.USERSLIST = firestore.collection<Users>('users').valueChanges(); so I tried to do what u tell me in the private search, but I got a error when I tried to get infos from firebase: Argument of type 'Observable<Users[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Users[]'. Type 'Observable<Users[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Users[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more

Comment: I changed declarations from country to users, because I want to list my Users collections on the datatable

Comment: It does not work for me, I'm using the last example on this page, with filter and pagination https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples